# Is the sum of a closed set and a subspace closed?

Tags: real-analysis

We define the sum of two sets $A$ and $B$ to be $$A+B=\{x+y ~|~ x \in A, y \in B \}.$$ Now let's suppose $A,B$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A$ is closed and $B$ is a subspace. Does it follow that $A+B$ closed?

Comment: Subspace?${{{}}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No take for example $\mathbb{R}^2$ and as the subspace the $x$-axis. The closed set is the graph of the exponential function, it is closed via the closed graph theorem. 
Now the sum of the two sets is :

$$A+B=\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: y>0\}$$
which is open and as $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected, $A+B$ can't be closed.

To be a bit more explicit let 
$$A=\{ (x,\exp(x))^T \in \mathbb{R}^2: x\in \mathbb{R}\}$$
and 
$$B=\{ (x,0)^T \in \mathbb{R}^2: x \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

Now we claim that the sum is 
$$A+B=\{ (x,y)^T \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y > 0\}.$$
As $\exp(x)>0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ we see that
$$ A+B \subseteq \{ (x,y)^T \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y > 0\}$$ 
obviously holds. On the other hand given $(x,y)^T$ with $y>0$ we 
see that $(\log(y),y)^T \in A$ and $(x-\log(y),0)^T \in B$. 
Hence 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\log(y)\\
y
\end{pmatrix} + 
\begin{pmatrix}
x-\log(y)\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
and so we see the equality.